# How to import SSIS package from file folder in integration services catalogs?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am importing SSIS packages from file folder.I follow the steps for importing packages , but while selecting package getting error:

> One or more selected packages are not ready.

Instead of `Ready` it showing `Error` in that column.

In message column it displaying error:

> The connection "{AF110402-8A0D-4BB8-8C20-520B747D1357}" is not found.

This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
Below i attached error page.

[image]

Comment: From the link mentioned in the comments below https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssis-connection-managers/ you can find the difference between project and package connection manager. It looks like you are using project connection manager which prevents you from deploying a single package. Deploy the project at once or replace project connection managers with package connections.

Answer (score 0):

I this the main problem is that you are trying to do a single deployment process, while the deployed package uses a Project connection manager.

You must use Project deployment model or edit the package and use local package connection manager instead of connection managers created at project level.

In addition, you can read more about deployment model in the following article:

- [Deploy Integration Services (SSIS) Projects and Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Here i want to run dtsx package for that purpose i am importing Package.dtsx from file.What need to do run dtsx package on sql server?

Comment: @ShivaniKhot you cannot since you are using a project connection manager https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssis-connection-managers/